# How do I monitor Tomcat6 with JVisualvm in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, jmx, jvisualvm

I'm trying to set up JVisualVm to monitor a Tomcat 6 instance (running on Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS). I've seen other questions, but none of them directly answer my problem. I try to connect to Tomcat with JVisualvm and it comes back with a "Cannot connect" error - but there are TCP connections being made to the server; the server drops the connection after a short burst of traffic.

I have already added this to /etc/default/tomcat6 and restarted tomcat6

```
# This enables JMX in order to permit VisualVM to profile the JVM.
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

I started rmiregistry using default settings:

```
rmiregistry &
```

I haven't started `jstatd`; installing it on the server requires the full JDK which requires X libraries. I'm not about to install X just to get one single binary.

I wonder if not running `jstatd` would have something to do with it; I was of the impression that I needed neither RMI nor jstatd, as long as I could use JMX directly via the JMX port.

There is no firewall in between the server and the JVisualvm client, and the iptables host firewall is open. Using `jconsole` results in the same error.

Running JVisualVM against the local Ubuntu 10.04 machine (by using its IP address and JMX port) and adding a JMX instance works fine - and I'm running neither `rmiregistry` nor `jstatd` - though the monitor shows RMI threads running.

Question: What must I do (either on the server or the client) in order to be able to monitor Tomcat (and other Java programs) via JMX with JVisualVM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If jconsole is failing, that's what I'd lead with - it's more basic than VVM - jconsole ships with the JDK, right?, so the answers you get are more likely to be on point.

Comment: No: the error message was exactly the same. I understand, too, that jconsole has reached end-of-life as well.

Comment: @Ladlestein VisualVM also ships with JDK.

Comment: True. However, the JDK and VisualVM are separate in the Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no firewall, try to set java.rmi.server.hostname system property for your Tomcat. Add this to your Tomcat's JAVA_OPTS:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<IP address of Ubuntu Server>
```

You don't need to start `rmiregistry` and you don't need to run `jstatd` to be able to monitor your Tomcat remotely.

Comment: That's what I did finally: worked like charm! However, I did have to start rmiregistry... Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't know why you need rmiregistry. Normally JMX connection works fine without explicitly started rmiregistry. Which connection string are you using to connect to your remote Tomcat?

Comment: I'm just specifying a JMX connection: `host:port` - that's all. I'll probably try working it again without the rmiregistry running.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: `jstatd` does not require X libraries, it only depends on them via some other recommended package. You can make `aptitude` or `apt-get` skip installation of recommended packages and have `jstatd` installed without any X11 libraries.

For `aptitude`, go into options ➞ preferences ➞ Install recommended packages automatically. For `apt-get`, see [this question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179060/how-not-to-install-recommended-and-suggested-packages).